# Can't add programmatic controls in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a page in ASP.NET, and I'm dynamically adding a subclass of WebControls.Button to the `Controls` data member of a pre-existing static TableCell. The button displays fine in the browser as expected. But when I click the button, the event handler I added for `button.Click` is not being called. Any suggestions as to why this is?

```
var controls = this.displaytable.Rows[i].Cells[j].Controls;
var button = new TableButton(j, i);
button.Click += new EventHandler(this.button_Click);
button.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
button.Text = "Available";
controls.Add(button);
```

Comment: Where is this code placed? Dynamic controls must be recreated on postback, otherwise you won't be able to handle their postback events.

Comment: Check out my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939313/dynamically-assign-button-events-in-c-asp-net/5939408#comment-6845140

Comment: I checked that page and re-created the controls. It did not fix the problem.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a more complete code sample. The button must be recreated and re-added to the control tree before the postback events are fired - the Load phase is your last call. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx for control lifecycle details. What you should take into account: if the button should preserve its view state, you must re-add it no later than during Init. The button should also have the same ID assigned before and after postback, otherwise it won't raise its postback events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically added buttons must be created on every request, most likely it is sufficient before raising postback events (e.g. OnLoad). Button needs to have an explicit ID sometime:

```
var controls = this.displaytable.Rows[i].Cells[j].Controls;
var button = new TableButton(j, i);
button.Click += new EventHandler(this.button_Click);
button.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
button.Text = "Available";
button.Id = string.Format("TableButton_{0}_{1}", j, i);
controls.Add(button);
```

This SO answer may help little bit: [ASP.NET dynamic Command Button event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775788/asp-net-dynamic-command-button-event-not-firing/1785769#1785769).